# Magento 2 How to get OptionTypeId of product custom option?

Tags: magento2, product

How to get
`OptionTypeId`
of custom option of simple product with option type field or area. Option type dropdown return the value of
`OptionTypeId`
but I also want this value with option type field or area.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
 $customOptions = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option')->getProductOptionCollection($_product);

    foreach($customOptions as $optionKey => $optionVal){
           foreach($optionVal->getValues() as $valuesKey => $valuesVal) {
                  echo $valuesVal->getId().' '.$valuesVal->getTitle();
           }
    }
```

Comment: `$optionVal->getValues()` It will return OptionTypeId if option type is dropdown, checkbox or radio. I want optionTypeId with option type text and area.

Comment: in textarea field you did not get option. because textarea have no option.

Answer (score 0):

Also using below code you can check product have custom option or not ?

```
<?php
namespace namespace\modulename\Model;

use Exception;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class ProductOptions
{
    private $logger;
    private $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }


    public function hasOptionsProduct()
    {
        $sku = '24-WG080';
        $hasOptions = false;
        try {
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
            $hasOptions = $product->hasOptions();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            throw new Exception($exception->getMessage());
        }
        return $hasOptions;
    }
}
```

if product has custom option then you can get optionTypeId().